# Google Map set direction in Grayscale mode

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2

is it possible to set the direction of google Maps in grayscale(black&white) mode on the website when users select stores and want to check the direction?

I have grayscale Map on my website but when the user tries to see the direction, direction detail shows in color so is there any possible way to show that direction also in black&white?

[image]

Comment: What does your code look like?  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.  You _should_ be able to customize the colors of the polyline and the markers created by the DirectionsRenderer.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, yes, setting the Directions polyline colors can be changed to match your grayscale map styling.

This can be done by modifying the [DirectionsRendererOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/directions#DirectionsRendererOptions)' polylineOptions.

```
var directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    suppressMarkers: true,
    polylineOptions:{
        strokeColor: "#808080",
        strokeWeight: 10
    }
});
```

As you can notice, I also removed the default directions marker by setting `suppressMarkers` to `true`. That way, I can create a new marker that I could modify to match the grayscale color as well.

Please find the working sample [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vr564Lny/)